# What would happen if lightning struck a salt deposit?

Tags: electricity, lightning

I'm not familiar with the formulae involved in lightning discharge, so please bear with me here.

As far as I'm aware, lightning (that is, cloud-to-ground lightning) tends to do one of three things, depending on what is struck:

1. The lightning is grounded
2. The lightning causes a chemical reaction (ex. if it strikes wood and ignites it)
3. The energy carried by the lightning causes particles struck to scatter (ex. if it strikes dirt)

I know that if it strikes sand, for instance, it causes a combination of #2 (some of it turns into glass) and #3 (much of it scatters).

What would happen if it struck an exposed salt deposit?

1. How much of it would melt, if any? How much would scatter, if any? Is there a fourth option not listed above that would apply?
2. I assume that, due to chaos theory, you can't predict precisely *how* it would scatter. However, is there a general rule that, say, if lightning strikes the right side of the deposit, the salt would scatter toward the left? Or that, if a lightning bolt carries X amount of energy, that it would produce Y amount of momentum in the salt, causing it to be flung Z meters into the air?
3. As an extension of question 2, how does the shape and volume of the salt deposit affect the calculations?
4. Can the above formulae be generalized to other compounds?

Comment: To downvoter: please explain?

Answer (score 1):

Lightening is simply a huge amount of current passing through a small region. In the case of a lightning conductor, since resistance is low, there is no heating. When lightning strike any other material, there is a high resistance and consequently heating. The energy causing the heating is  square of the current multiplied by the resistance.

The chemical reactions, sand melting, trees burning and so on are caused by heating. Dry salt is an insulator but salt is hygroscopic. So the consequences for lightning strike on a salt deposit will depend more on the water content.

The scattering by which you obviously mean small particles being thrown to a distance is due to high velocity air movement which is another consequence of the heating.

There is no way to model this and develop mathematical models. There are too many variables.

Chaos theory is completely different. Chaos in everyday language is disorder but in chaos thoery it is the consequence of two or more mathematically well defined parts. The easiest is when one process leads to an increase and another to a decrease. Chaos is the result when these two are precisely matched in some specific ways.